# crop the required area with point in hand

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence, feature-detection

I have the below output with finger tips detected and the points are pushed into the vector.
The below is the output I got and blue points are the information I have.  With these information can I crop the finger part alone? If so can you please provide your suggestions.

**Output I got and points information:**

[image]

**Area to be cropped is marked in red:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

would that work if you connect blue 2 and blue 3, blue 3 and blue 4? That will segment the middle 2 fingers. Then draw a line passing blue 4 and parallel with the green line passing blue 5, and another line passing blue 3 parallel with the green line passing blue 3

Comment: But these numberings are not same always. It depends on the convexity defects found.

Comment: Yes. But in most cases it is feasible if you already succeeded in the corner detection (tip on the fingers, and connections between fingers).